# Populate a variable with a subtree

Tags: xslt

in a `version="2.0"` stylesheet:

the following code produces the correct output

```
<xsl:variable name="obj">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="t:ReferencedObjectType='Asset'">
      <xsl:value-of select="/t:Flow/t:FHeader/t:Producer/t:Repository" />
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:value-of select="$obj"/>
```

but this one does not

```
<xsl:variable name="obj">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="t:ReferencedObjectType='Asset'">
      <xsl:value-of select="/t:Flow/t:FHeader/t:Producer" />
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:value-of select="$obj/t:Repository"/>
```

How can I get the second code to run as expected ?
If needed, is there a solution in v3 ?

---

this code does not run either

```
<xsl:variable name="obj">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="t:ReferencedObjectType='Asset'">
      <xsl:copy-of select="/t:Flow/t:FHeader/t:Producer" />
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:value-of select="$obj/t:Repository"/>
```

relevant xml input

```
<Flow>
  <FHeader>
    <Producer>
      <Repository>tests.com</Repository>
    </Producer>
  </FHeader>
</Flow>
```

Comment: `xsl:value-of` only returns the string value of a node. You probably want to use `xsl:copy-of` to copy the `t:Repository` element itself.

Comment: @TimC i edit my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply select `<xsl:variable name="obj" select="/t:Flow/t:FHeader/t:Producer/t:Repository[current()/t:ReferencedObjectType='Asset']"/>`. Or, as Tim already commented, use `xsl:copy-of`, also taking into account that you then later on need e.g. `$obj/t:Producer/t:Repository` to select the right level.

Or learn about the `as` attribute and use e.g. `<xsl:variable name="obj" as="element()*">...<xsl:copy-of select="/t:Flow/t:FHeader/t:Producer"/> ...</xsl:variable>`, then you later on can use e.g. `$obj/t:Repository`.

There is also `xsl:sequence` to select input nodes instead of copying them, in particular with `xsl:variable` if you use the `as` attribute. This might consume less memory.

Furthermore XPath 2 and later have `if (condition-expression) then expression else expression` conditional expressions at the expression level so you might not need XSLT with `xsl:choose/xsl:when` but could use the `<xsl:variable name="obj" select="if (t:ReferencedObjectType='Asset']) then /t:Flow/t:FHeader/t:Producer else if (...) then ... else ()"/>`, that way you would select e.g. an input `t:Producer` element anyway and if you use the variable you can directly select the `t:Repository` child.

Comment: yes, but there are more `xsl:when` to come, I reduce my code for brevity/clarity

Comment: I will learn about `as`, it (for now magically) fixed my probelm